# how to associate lamda function to bot alias in amazon lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bots

I'm recently working on creating a bot with Amazon Lex. Reading the aws tutorials, I saw that they were outdated. This wasn't a problem till I needed to hook a aws lambda function to my intent fulfillment. I discovered that I need to hook the lambda function to a bot alias (witch I created, but have not discovered how to hook the function) to be able to test the bot. I'm stuck on this problem. I would appreciate if someone that has already built a bot could explain me how to hook the lambda function to the bot intent.

Comment: Does this help https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gs-cli-update-lambda.html

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you're working with version 2 of AWS Lex. A lot of people are experiencing the issue of associating a Lambda function with a Lex bot.

AWS have chosen a pretty weird way to configure this.

Please take a look at this answer that I had previously written on how to link a Lambda function to your Lex bot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73621837/8880593

Answer (score 0):

{
action: "lambda:InvokeFunction",
principal: new iam.AnyPrincipal(),
}
Add this permission to your lambda
If it works, you can limit your principal later on